# Prove that this Markov chain is irreducible if and only if there exist infinitely many $k\geq0$ such that $q_{k}>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

We consider the Markov chain $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n\geq0}$
  on $\mathbb{N}$
  whose transition matrix $P=\left(p_{k,l}\right)_{k,l\geq0}$
  given by

$$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}
  p_{k,k-1}=q_{k},p_{k,k+1}=p_{k}$$

with $p_{k}+q_{k}=1$
  and $p_{k}>0$
  for any $k\geq0$
 .

Prove that this Markov chain is irreducible if and only if there exist infinitely many $k\geq0$
  such that $q_{k}>0$
 .

How to prove it? I need some hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Suppose by contradiction that there is a finite number of indices $k$ such that $q_k>0$. Let $k^*$ be the biggest of these indices. What happens if my Markov chain jumps to state $k^*+1$?

Comment: $p_{k^*+1,k^*}=0$ right?

Comment: @AleZok A more urgent task than embarking the OP in the considerations in your comment, seems to be to mention that the result does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. The chain is irreducible only if *all* $q_k\gt0$. If $q_j=0$, there is no way to get from state $j$ to states $\lt j$.

Comment: Why do you talk "This is false"?

Comment: @user109584: I don't understand the question. I justified my claim that your statement is false in the remainder of the answer.

Comment: The answer starts by "This is false" because the author of the answer claims that the result the question asks to prove ("this Markov chain is irreducible if and only if there exist infinitely many k≥0 such that qk>0.") does not hold. (Needless to say, the author of the answer is right.)

Comment: Do you mean the statement "if" is false?

Comment: @user109584: Yes, you could put it that way.

Comment: Why? I think it's true. Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: @user109584: But I did! Please explain what part of the argument in my answer isn't clear.

Comment: I mean if the chain is irreducible then there exist infinitely many k≥0 such that qk>0 .

Comment: You think that's false right?

Comment: @user109584: No, that's correct. That's the "only if" part. You summarized correctly above that I'm saying that the "if" part is false.

Comment: If there exist infinitely many k≥0 such that qk>0 then the chain is irreducible, I think this statement is also true. Why do you think it's false?

Comment: @user109584: Look, I've replied three times now that I gave the reason in the answer. I'm not going to reply to further questions before you point out what part of that you find unclear or unconvincing, and why.

Comment: I agree with you that The chain is irreducible only if all qk>0. But the "if" part, I think it's also true.

Comment: @user109584: That's an immediate contradiction. For those two statements to be consistent, "infinitely many" would have to imply "all". It clearly doesn't.

Comment: I think by "infinitely many" the question means "all".

Comment: @user109584: If it does, you should throw that book away. "Infinitely many" does not mean "all". (Also, even if the book is bad, your interpretation seems unlikely since "infinitely many" is preceded in the question by "there exist", and "there exist all" makes no sense.)

Comment: Funny to see user @joriki *almost* raising their voice... This requires some. :-)